# Executing a SPARQL query USING rdf and owlready2 doesn't stop

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, owlready

I perform an advanced query in Quran ontology, first I tried the query on Apache Jena Fuseki. It gave me the correct results so I copied the query into my code in google collab but unfortunately, the run doesn't stop using both owlready2 and rdf.

This is my code using owlready2:

```
from owlready2 import *
onto_path.append("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus")
go = get_ontology("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/quran_data_full.owl").load()
obo = get_namespace("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/")
query = """
PREFIX qu: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/qu/qu#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX qur: <http://quranontology.com/Resource/>


SELECT  distinct ?prophetLabel
WHERE {
?person rdfs:subClassOf* qur:Person.   
?prophet rdf:type  ?person.  
?prophet  rdfs:label ?prophetLabel.
?verse rdf:type qur:Verse.
?prophet qur:MentionedIn ?verse.
?verse2 rdf:type qur:Verse.  
?word rdf:type qur:Word. 
?letter rdf:type qur:PronounRefDifferentVerse. 
?word qur:IsPartOf ?verse2.
?letter qur:IsPartOf ?word.
?letter  qur:ReferToVerse ?verse.
?verse2 rdfs:label ?textSimple2.
?verse rdfs:label ?textSimple.
FILTER ((REGEX(STR(?prophetLabel), "[ء-ي]+" ,"i"))).
FILTER (REGEX(STR(?textSimple2), "برا بوالديه" ,"i")).
  } 
"""
d = list(default_world.sparql(query))
print(d)
```

This is my code using rdf:

```
parsingGraph = rdflib.Graph()
parsingGraph.parse ('/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/quran_data_full.owl', format='application/rdf+xml')
quran_data_full = rdflib.Namespace('/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/quran_data_full.owl')
parsingGraph.bind('quran_data_full', quran_data_full)
query = """
PREFIX qu: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/qu/qu#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX qur: <http://quranontology.com/Resource/>


SELECT  distinct ?prophetLabel
WHERE {
?person rdfs:subClassOf* qur:Person.   
?prophet rdf:type  ?person.  
?prophet  rdfs:label ?prophetLabel.
?verse rdf:type qur:Verse.
?prophet qur:MentionedIn ?verse.
?verse2 rdf:type qur:Verse.  
?word rdf:type qur:Word. 
?letter rdf:type qur:PronounRefDifferentVerse. 
?word qur:IsPartOf ?verse2.
?letter qur:IsPartOf ?word.
?letter  qur:ReferToVerse ?verse.
?verse2 rdfs:label ?textSimple2.
?verse rdfs:label ?textSimple.
FILTER ((REGEX(STR(?prophetLabel), "[ء-ي]+" ,"i"))).
FILTER (REGEX(STR(?textSimple2), "برا بوالديه" ,"i")).
  } 
"""
result = parsingGraph.query(query)
for row in result:
    print(row.prophetLabel)
```

This is the output in Apache Jena Fuseki:
[image]

What are the possible alternatives to execute this query?

You can see the full content of quran_data_full.owl file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xLMYASvHkJt1aoVqxG7A7tpbA6RX6nok/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: what is the purpose of the triple patterns leading to `?textSimple`? I mean, you're not using this variable for anything. Also, REGEX is expensive, a fulltext index configured in Jena could speed up things

Comment: Moreover, did you load the data into TDB or is it in-memory? If TDB, computing statistics could guide the query optimizer

Comment: @UninformedUser text simple I may use it as an output later, but I don’t think it’s the cause of the problem

Comment: It is in-memory, how can I use the one with the optimizer?

Comment: just load the data into a TDB. Then compute the TDB stats. Then use the TDB in the Fuseki configuration as the backend.

Comment: Is it possible over google colab? kindly provide me with some examples.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213122/how-to-connect-apache-jena-fuseki-to-python-code-in-google-colab