# How to connect Apache Jena Fuseki to python code in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, sparql, jena, fuseki

I have an ontology and I want tp perform some advanced SPARQL queries on it using Apache Jena Fuseki over a Google Collab environment, is it possible?

I tried this code in my local device and it's working, however I want to work in google collab.

```
!pip install sparqlwrapper
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper(
    'http://localhost:3030/Quran/sparql'
)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

sparql.setQuery("""
   PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
                PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
                PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
                PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
                PREFIX qur: <http://quranontology.com/Resource/>
               SELECT  distinct ?prophetLabel 
                  WHERE {

                  ?verse2 rdf:type qur:Verse.
                  ?verse2 rdfs:label ?textSimple2.  
                  ?word rdf:type qur:Word. 
                  ?word qur:IsPartOf ?verse2.
                  ?letter rdf:type qur:PronounRefDifferentVerse.          
                  ?letter qur:IsPartOf ?word.
                  ?verse rdf:type qur:Verse.
                  ?person rdfs:subClassOf* qur:Person.   
                  ?prophet rdf:type  ?person.  
                  ?prophet  rdfs:label ?prophetLabel.
                  ?prophet qur:MentionedIn ?verse.
                  ?letter  qur:ReferToVerse ?verse.             
                  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?textSimple2), 'برا بوالديه' ,"i")).
                  }
    """
)
try:
    ret = sparql.queryAndConvert()
    for r in ret["results"]["bindings"]:
        print(r)  
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Using the same code in google collab, gives me this error:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
```

Comment: I doubt that Google colab has access to your local Fuseki. I mean, the URL is localhost and this would just go the the Colab VM

Comment: So how can I do that?

Comment: You might want to expose your local port 3030 to the public by using tools for forwarding local port, like https://ngrok.com/ . Definitely not for production, but good for testing.